# How can I find the largest integer?

Tags: objective-c

I have 5 ints and I'm trying to find which single one has the largest value. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
if (louis > harry , matt , bob , jack) {
    name.text = @"Louis";
}
```

but it doesn't work right.

Comment: They don't look like ints to me

Comment: You're probably better off putting your data in an array along with an array of names. Then when you find the index of the array item with the maximum value, you can use that index to look up the name.

Answer (score 2):

Use arrays! Put the integers in an array. If you can don't even use separate named `int` variables and use an `int` array instead.

```
int values[5] = {louis, harry, matt, bob, jack};
NSArray *names = @[@"Louis", @"Harry", @"Matt", @"Bob", @"Jack"];
int highestValue = -INFINITY;
NSString *highestName = nil;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (values[i] > highestValue) {
        highestValue = values[i];
        highestName = names[i];
    }
}
```

There are many solutions to your problem. The above only a general and very simple one.

It simply puts your integers into an array and uses a loop to find the largest one. It then gets the according name from an other array of strings. Note that the `int` array is a plain C array, while the string array is an Objective-C style [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) or [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) objects.

By the way, your approach doesn't work, because it's not valid C code. If you want to do it like that, do it as I did below. But I really recommend using arrays instead as it's easier to read an maintain.

```
if (louis > harry && louis > matt && louis > bob && louis > jack) {
    name.text = @"Louis";
} else if (harry > louis && harry > matt && harry > bob && harry > jack) {
    name.text = @"Harry";
} ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

*Note that I don't have any experience with xcode, I'm just writing what I can find*

As far as I can see there is no way to call `fmax` with an arbitrary number of arguments, so you would have to loop through your variables, something like this:

```
switch(fmax(louis,fmax(harry,fmax(matt,fmax(bob,jack)))) {
    case louis: name.text = @"Louis"; break;
    case harry: name.text = @"Harry"; break;
    case matt : name.text = @"Matt";  break;
    case bob  : name.text = @"Bob";   break;
    case jack : name.text = @"Jack";  break;
}
```